# Does gcc version matter for kernel modules

Tags: gcc, kernel, embedded-linux

We've been compiling kernel modules for an embedded powerpc system for a few years now and generally things are ok with some rare unexplained stability problems. Recently a collegue pointed out that kernel modules should be compiled with the same compiler as the kernel. After doing a bit of digging i find that the kernel (montavista linux 2.4.20) was compiled with gcc3.4.1 and we've been using (denx eldk) gcc4.0.0. I've recently built gcc4.7.1 for our userspace code but loading kernel modules built with this version cause the system to crash. I then build gcc3.4.1 from source and some builds work and some don't - think i may have an issue with the make scripts but thats another story.

So my question: Is my collegue correct? And if so can anyone explain what is different in the resulting .o file that causes the incompatibility?

Answer (score 4):

Wow, that kernel has been around a long time, since the early days of my former MontaVista employment!  I'm not sure there is a hard fast answer here, but I know if it were me, I would be concerned about compiler differences.  The Linux kernel has always been sensitive to compiler versions, in part because of it's sheer size and complexity.  The kernel uses lots of GNU extensions, and actually makes a pretty good stress test for a new compiler build.

You can discover what compiler was used to build the kernel simply by looking at the output of /proc/version (I think that exists that far back in the 2.4.20 kernel days, but I could be wrong on that.) $ cat /proc/version.  It certainly works for modern kernels and has been in the kernel for a long time.

My first suggestion would be to upgrade the kernel to something more modern, but I suspect that's not really an option, or you wouldn't be asking the question! ;)

I suspect that even a compiler expert (not me) would have a hard time answering the question "what's different".  But do this simple test.  Compile your module with 3.4.1, and then 4.7.  The resulting objects (.ko files) will certainly be different.

The reality is, bugs exist in all software, and may lurk for ages until something comes along to stimulate the bug.  See my blog post here: http://blogs.mentor.com/chrishallinan/blog/2012/05/18/fun-with-toolchain-versions for a perfect example of this.

Now I'm not saying that's your issue, but I think I'd feel alot better if my modules and kernel were both compiled with the same compiler version.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

**It matters**.

Mostly you would encounter the following, i.e.

```
rmmod: ERROR: could not remove 'hello': Device or resource busy
```